# 3D and physic simulation with java

Tags: java, 3d, simulator

im a student and i must do a semester project.

i must make a physic simulator of Magnetic forces on a current loop.

I don't know anything about simulation coding either physic with JAVA.

i would like to read your recommendations for make this project. 
The teacher told us that the software have to be coded in JAVA. 
i looked for simulation in google but there weren't good information

i don't know a lot about JAVA 3D so, i've to learn several things, offcourse.
THANKS for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn a lot by looking at the source for JBullet, a java port of the very popular Bullet physics engine. I don't know if your project is to write your own engine or you can use an existing one, but with either task you will learn a lot by studying JBullet.

Link: http://jbullet.advel.cz